# Quick way to initialize list of numbered strings?

Tags: c#, string, list, numbers, initialization

How can I quickly create a string list with numbered strings?

Right now I'm using:

```
var str = new List<string>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    str.Add("This is string number " + i);
}
```

This works, however I wonder if there's a quicker way to initialize such a string list, maybe in one or two lines?

Comment: By "quicker" do you mean "less typing" or "runs faster"?

Comment: I actually meant less typing. Speed is not an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => "This is string number " + i).ToList();
```

Comment: Wow, 14 whole seconds faster :)

Comment: Awesome... thank you, I had something like this in mind but I'm not good with LINQ :)

Comment: @MartinSvensson - LINQ is simple n amazing, just check it out, you will be better!

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => "This is string number " + i).ToList();
```

---

Comment: For completeness: You can also do: var items = (from number in Enumerable.Range(1, 10) select "This is string number " + number).ToList();